# MySQL remove corrupted Tablespace

Tags: mysql, tablespaces

this is my problem: for unknown reasons, I have a tablespace that corresponds to a table that no longer exists. I think the machine was not restarted correctly and this caused the damage. I want to recreate the table but when I try to do so, it gives me an error of an already existing tablespace. Even physically deleting the file, the problem persists as MySQL internally maintains references to this tablespace. The only solution I was able to implement was to recreate the table in MyISAM mode instead of InnoDB. Can you tell me if there is any way to restore the entire system and definitively eliminate the corrupted tablespace and then recreate the table correctly? Thank you